# Spring WebFlux Functional Endpoints + @JsonView how?

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4 WebFlux with Functional Endpoints.

I want to return different models in GET /books and GET /books/{id}. A brief model in the former and the full model in the latter.

I can filter properties out from the JSON Serialization by using @JsonIgnore but that removes any specific field from all responses that use this model.

Jackson provides @JsonView as a solution to this but that solution is only compatible with Annotated Controllers and I'm using Functional Endpoints like this:

```
@Configuration
public class BookRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routeBooks(BookHandler bookHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions
            .route(RequestPredicates.GET("/books")
                    .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), bookHandler::getBooks)
            .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/books/{id}")
                    .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), bookHandler::getBook);
    }
}
```

So basically I'm asking if there is any known way that I can use @JsonView with Functional Endpoints or if there is any other way I can achieve what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify JSON views using serialization hints as bellow:

```
public class BookHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getBook(ServerRequest request) {
        return ServerResponse
                .ok()
                .hint(Jackson2CodecSupport.JSON_VIEW_HINT, MyJacksonView.class)
                .body(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how make it dynamic? i mean by user role(reactive spring security)

Comment: @nekperu15739 were you able to find a way to make it dynamic using role in spring security?

Comment: Hi @a.developer, yes I did, as Sebastian mention, just need to populate the hint